# how to set custom view resolver for view path in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have lib (spring-social) with controller, that have following code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{providerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String connectionStatus(@PathVariable String providerId, NativeWebRequest request, Model model) {
    setNoCache(request);
    processFlash(request, model);
    List<Connection<?>> connections = connectionRepository.findConnections(providerId);
    setNoCache(request);
    if (connections.isEmpty()) {
        return connectView(providerId); 
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("connections", connections);
        return connectedView(providerId);           
    }
}
```

return of this code - path like /connect/twitterConnected. Than spring try to find view resolver for this path. I don't want to create view for this path, but instead redirect to another view. How cat i handle this path and create RedirectView for this? 
Can i get request parameters from this method in my view resolver?

Comment: Does `redirect:` not do what you need?

Comment: @chrylis, it's library code, i can't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve redirect to a different view than the url returned from legacy code controller by creating a class which extends UrlBasedViewResolver and overriding buildView method in it.

```
    public class CustomizedViewResolver extends UrlBasedViewResolver {
        @Override
        protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
            String newViewName;
            if(viewName.equals("YourLegacyCodeViewName")){
                newViewName = "ViewNameYouWantToRedirect";
            }else{
                newViewName = viewName;
            }
            return super.buildView(newViewName);
        }
    }
```

Make sure that this customized view resolver is higher order in precedence to InternalResourceViewResolver.
For more information about buildView method, check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html#buildView%28java.lang.String%29).